# How to use an XSL variable as a condition to evaluate XPath?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have faced an issue when using a variable as a condition for XPath evaluation. I have the following template which works fine:

```
<xsl:template name="typeReasonDic">
    <xsl:variable name="dic" select="$schema//xs:simpleType[@name = 'type_reason_et']"/>
    <!-- do something with the variable -->
</xsl:template>
```

However, when I change it to look like this:

```
<xsl:template name="typeReasonDic">
    <xsl:param name="choose_dic" select="@name = 'type_reason_et'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="dic" select="$schema//xs:simpleType[$choose_dic]"/>
    <!-- do something with the variable -->
</xsl:template>
```

it fails to find the desired node.

What I wish to get is a template with a *default* value for `$choose_dic` which can be overriden where necessary.

What am I missing here?

**UPD:** there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682151/xslvariable-as-xpath-value-for-other-xsl-tag) link I found with the description of what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 without an extension function.  The problem is that with

```
<xsl:template name="typeReasonDic">
    <xsl:param name="choose_dic" select="@name = 'type_reason_et'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="dic" select="$schema//xs:simpleType[$choose_dic]"/>
    <!-- do something with the variable -->
</xsl:template>
```

the `<xsl:param>` will evaluate its `select` expression a single time in the current context and store the true/false result of this evaluation in the `$choose_dic` variable.  The `<xsl:variable>` will therefore select either *all* `xs:simpleType` elements under the `$schema` (if `$choose_dic` is true) or *none* of them (if `$choose_dic`) is false.  This is very different from

```
<xsl:variable name="dic" select="$schema//xs:simpleType[@name = 'type_reason_et']"/>
```

which will evaluate `@name = 'type_reason_et'` repeatedly, in the context of each `xsl:simpleType`, and select those elements for which the expression evaluated to true.

If you store the XPath expression as a string you can use an extension function such as [`dyn:evaluate`](http://www.exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/) or the XSLT 3.0 [`xsl:evaluate`](http://saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/xsl-elements/evaluate.html) element if you're using Saxon.

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
<xsl:param name="choose_dic" select="@name = 'type_reason_et'"/>
```

the XSL engine will try to evaluate "@name = 'type_reason_et'" as an XPath expression, and will assign the RESULT to your variable.

You should use the following variable declaration instead:

```
<xsl:param name="choose_dic">@name = 'type_reason_et'</xsl:param>
```

This is the default value, but you can override it when you call your template by using xsl:with-param.

Comment: See the link in my updated question. The accepted answer there seems to do exactly what I'm trying to do. I tried to replace the `<xsl:param>` with `<xsl:variable>` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is not a macro language where you might be able to concatenate your code at run-time from strings and then evaluate them dynamically. So in general for your purpose you would need an extension function to evaluate an XPath expression stored in a string or you need to look into a new XSLT 3.0 features like http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/xsl-elements/evaluate.xml.

What is possible in the scope of XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 is doing e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="p1" select="'foo'"/>

<xsl:variable name="v1" select="//bar[@att = $p1]"/>
```

where the `param` holds a value you compare to other value, for instance those in a node like an attribute or element node.

Comment: But what if I need to alter the condition to be `&lt;`, for example. And how come there is an accepted answer on what I'm trying to do? See the link in my question update.

Comment: If you didn't accept the answer, I don't know who did. Everything said in that answer is correct. But perhaps you've confused things by changing the question after getting an answer - personally I think that's best avoided.