# How to pass parameter in xsl apply-templates from Camel route

Tags: java, xslt, xpath, apache-camel

I want to pass xPath from Camel route to XSLT transformation and use it in `apply-templates select`. According to Camel documentation I have set parameter as Header and declare it in XSLT transformation. I am using xslt 2.0

I can see te value of xPath, but I does not work in  `apply-templates select`. See the examples for detailed information:

route.java

```
from("direct:myRoute")
.setHeader("myParam", constant("/myxPath/example") 
.to(XSLT_PATH);
```

xslt.xml

```
<xsl:param name="myParam"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="DummyElement">
        <xsl:element name="ChildElement">
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:value-of select="$myParam"/> - this will return provided xpath (/myxPath/example) 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$myParam" - this doesn't work 
                             mode="mymode"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

I have done also test with variable and it also does not working:

```
<xsl:param name="myParam"/>
<xsl:variable name="myVariable" select="$myParam"/> - change here
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="DummyElement">
        <xsl:element name="ChildElement">
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$myVariable"  - change here
                             mode="mymode"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

but when I provide xpath in param select all is working properly:

```
<xsl:param name="myParam" select="/myxPath/example"/> -change here
<xsl:variable name="myVariable" select="$myParam"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="DummyElement">
        <xsl:element name="ChildElement">
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$myVariable" 
                             mode="mymode"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

I looked at the topics which already exist, but I didn't get the solution. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not familiar with Camel and its interaction with XSLT but I guess your code sets the parameter value as a string so in XSLT you would have e.g. `<xsl:param name="myParam" select="'/myxPath/example'"/>` as the equivalent and obviously selecting a string is not going to work with apply-templates. What kind of paths do you want to pass, how far to they vary? For limited needs like e.g. `//foo` and `//bar` you could use `//*[local-name() = $myParam]` and set `.setHeader("myParam", constant("foo")` I suppose.

Comment: @MartinHonnen is right. The real issue is not passing the parameter, but using a string containing your XPath. Reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682151/xslvariable-as-xpath-value-for-other-xsl-tag should give you some hints about this...

Comment: Thanks for responses, I changed my logic in order to not use $myVariable as a xPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default all headers from Camel message are available in XSLT. In my case I needed to put new header into my message:

```
.setHeader("myParam", constant("/myxPath/example"))
```

And I was correctly getting myParam in XSLT. However according to '@Martin Honnen' and @Orabîg comments, Camel is passing these parameters as strings, so in XSLT I've received:

```
<xsl:param name="myParam" select="'/myxPath/example'"/> - note additional single quotation mark
```

In XSLT 2.0 is not possible to convert `xsl:param` values from string to xpath directly.