# xpath expression not returning the right information

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need help to find the XPATH expression that would retrieve the address number for the "Home" site element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<location>
<name>
    <site>Work</site>
    <address>4589</address>
</name>
<name>
    <site>Home</site>
    <address>234</address>
</name>
<name>
    <site>Store</site>
    <address>58</address>
</name>
<name>
    <site>School</site>
    <address>712</address>
</name>
</location>
```

I tried this but it's not working :

```
/location/name[site:"Home"]/address
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close to correct `XPath`. Try to replace `:` with `=` as below:

```
/location/name[site="Home"]/address
```

This will return `address` element. If you want to retrieve `address` value, then add `/text()` as

```
/location/name[site="Home"]/address/text()
```

Comment: You are right ! Thanks a lot ! :-)  Now what if I want to use a variable in my expression ?  Would it look like something like this : /location/name[site=$place]/address

Comment: Yes I tried what you proposed and it works fine ! :-)  Now I am just trying to understand how it would work if I'd want to use a variable in my expression.

Comment: Actually I'm not much familiar with `xslt`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682151/xslvariable-as-xpath-value-for-other-xsl-tag) might help you

Comment: Thank you so much for your time @Andersson ! Have a great day and thanks for taking the time to help beginners like me ! :-)